# Changing the link text when using dataTable's show/hide function

Tags: jquery

I am using the dataTable script to easily sort data pulled from my database, and using their built-in function so show/hide certain columns:

```
        function fnShowHide(iCol) {
        var oTable = $('#inventory').dataTable();
        var bVis = oTable.fnSettings().aoColumns[iCol].bVisible;
        oTable.fnSetColumnVis( iCol, bVis ? false : true );
    }
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="cost" onclick="fnShowHide(10);">Cost</a>
```

Question is, how to I make it so that if the column is hidden the link text says "Show Cost" and if the column is visible have it say "Hide Cost"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will work. It appears you are assigning the column index to the onclick attribute, maybe add an id to the anchor to use as an accessor; something like:

```
function fnShowHide(iCol) {
        var oTable = $('#inventory').dataTable();
        var bVis = oTable.fnSettings().aoColumns[iCol].bVisible;
        oTable.fnSetColumnVis( iCol, bVis ? false : true );

        //--anchor text modifier
        var $anchor = $('#anchor_' + iCol);
        var albl = $anchor.text();
        if(albl.indexOf('Show')!=-1 || albl.indexOf('Hide')!=-1 ){
          albl = (bVis)? albl.replace('Show', 'Hide') : albl.replace('Hide', 'Show');
        }else{
          albl = (bVis)? 'Hide ' + albl : 'Show ' + albl; 
        }
        $anchor.text(albl)
    }
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="cost" 
id="anchor_10" onclick="fnShowHide(10);">Cost</a>
```

I had an error in my syntax: change applied to the following line should yeild the result you are looking for:

```
    if(albl.indexOf('Show')!=-1 || albl.indexOf('Hide')!=-1 ){
 /*this is affected line*/ albl = (bVis)? albl.replace('Show', 'Hide') : albl.replace('Hide', 'Show');
    }else{
```

Comment: It did change the text to "Hide," but if I click it again it does not toggle to "Show"

Comment: Is the bVis returning a Boolean? If not, that may be the issue. I would recommend trying with firebug if you have not, and console.dir([bVis, albl]); to show values as you trigger.